# Android app does not open with usb debugging enabled

Tags: adb, usb-debugging

I am using adb to run a few shell scripts on an android tv. The problem is, one of the apps which I need to use on the tv does not open while usb debugging is active. When trying to open the app it says "turn off usb debugging to use the app". Is there any way to bypass this restriction? Or to run adb without usb debugging?

Comment: As an Android developer you can directly query if ADB_ENABLED settings is enabled or disabled. There are only two options: modify the system so that it returns a wrong ADB state or modify the app to bypass the check. On a rooted device there may be a Magisk module to hide the state but I am not sure how complicated it is to root a TV.

Comment: How could I modify my system for it to return a fake ADB status? I can not modify the app, sadly.

Comment: As I said you need to unlock and root the device and then may be a Magisk module (assuming that Magisk manages root). But I don't have any experience with Android TV and rooting.